# Question about $profile.psextended

Tags: powershell

I found a powershell tip regarding $profile.psextended that returns all of the various Powershell profiles and their locations. Having never see that before I ran ($profile | get-member). psextended was not in the list of results.

Having access to some very helpful MVPs on another site I asked how the psextended property was found. Within minutes I got a reply that using ($profile | gm -View all) should do the trick. I tried this and still had no results matching what I was looking for. If you enter $profile. and keep hitting the tab button it scrolls through the possible matches. psextended is nowhere to be found. Am I losing my mind or just plain blind?

Any help would be appreciated as I do not want to frustrate or annoy the guy trying to help me.

Thanks.

--
Eric

Answer (score 4):

Every object, once assigned to a variable, is wrapped in a special semi-transparent object called a PSObject. This is powershell's way of trying to level the playing field for the different types of things that be assigned to a variable. There are four "special" properties exposing different things for any given variable in powershell:

```
ps> $o = 1
ps> $o.psobject
...
ps> $o.psadapted
...
ps> $o.psextended
...
ps> $o.psbase
...
```

You can read about these properties over on:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119140317/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powershell/archive/2006/11/24/what-s-up-with-psbase-psextended-psadapted-and-psobject.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. This was answered by Shay Levy (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/ScriptFanatic/) on another service. Posted here to close the topic.

$profile | get-member -Force

lists the result I was looking for and several more for me to check out.